# Shortest way to turn towards a target?

Tags: xna

Ive created a small tank-shooter-minigame, and is currently working on cpu control of other tanks.

A cpu tank knows the following:

- Its own facing, the direction its facing
- Its own position (X and Y)
- Its targets position (X and Y)

On top of that ive made it so that positive y is downwards instead of upwards. positive x direction is left to right.

How do i calculate the shortest way the cpu tank need to rotate to point on its target?

Lets say tank is at (3,3), facing 90 degrees (straight left) and Im at (4,7). What would the calucations be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there isn't an easier way to do this, I tend to revert to 3d vector math often, even if in 2d trigonometric solutions are better suited. Your question implies you are working in 2d, but the 3d math will still work. Hopefully, someone will come up with an easier algorithm for you, but if not, here is something.

I assume you mean the shortest way in an angular measurement. In this code, the result will be a positive angular value if the shortest way is CCW, negative if CW.

```
Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(3, 3);
Vector2 myPosition = new Vector2(4, 7);
Vector2 myFacingDirection2D = new Vector2(-1, 0);//facing straight left   
Vector3 directionToTarget3D = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(targetPosition - myPosition, 0));
Vector3 myFacingDirection3D = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(myFacingDir2D, 0);
Vector3 crossResult = Vector3.Cross(myFacingDirection3D, directionToTarget3d);
float dotFactor = Vector3.Dot(myFacingDirection3D, directionToTarget3D) < 0 ? MathHelper.Pi : 0f;

float angleToTarget = (dotFactor - (float)Math.Sin(crossResult.Length()) ) * Math.Sign(crossResult.Z);
```

If this turns out backwards (positive/negative wise) then reverse the order of the params in the Cross function.